# Deletar usuário da memória aspx c#

Tags: c#, lista, loop, aspx

Fala pessoal, beleza? Então, é o seguinte... Estou realizando um projeto onde não será necessário o uso de banco de dados. Porém, há necessidade de tabelas para guardar na memória alguns dados de pessoas. Para melhor usabilidade do sistema, gostaria de dar a opção do usuário de excluir qualquer pessoa que ele tenha adicionado anteriormente. Mas como sou novo na área, não sei como faço para excluir um usuário da memória.

No sistema há uma classe Pessoa.cs onde eu crio uma lista para guardar as informações das pessoas na memória:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Pessoas
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Nacionalidade { get; set; }
        public string Passaporte { get; set; }
        public string Identidade { get; set; }
        public string CPF { get; set; }
        public static List<Pessoas> pessoas = new List<Pessoas>();
        public List<Pessoas> Todos()
        {
            return Pessoas.pessoas;
        }
        public void Salvar()
        {
            Pessoas.pessoas.Add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Até aí tudo bem. Depois das inserções das pessoas é que vem o problema, eu não sei excluir qualquer uma delas. Já me disseram que eu preciso percorrer essa lista com um loop e achar qual o item que eu quero excluir. Mas eu não tenho ideia de como fazer isso. Alguém teria uma solução pra esse caso ou poderia me dar uma dica de como fazer o loop e deletar a "pessoa"?

Caso precisem de mais código, é só dizer. Preciso muito de ajuda!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019009/8469314

Answer (score 0):

Você pode pesquisar na coleção `Pessoas.pessoas` pela pessoa que deseja remover  com o `FirstOrDefault`. Caso o retorno não seja `null` (a pessoa foi encontrada), basta remover com o `Remove`. Abaixo segue um trecho de exemplo:

```
var p1 = new Pessoas() {
    CPF = "foo",
    Identidade = "111",
    Nacionalidade = "111",
    Nome = "111",
    Passaporte = "111"
};
p1.Salvar();

var p2 = new Pessoas() {
    CPF = "bar",
    Identidade = "222",
    Nacionalidade = "222",
    Nome = "222",
    Passaporte = "222"
};
p2.Salvar();

// Removendo a pessoa cujo CPF = "foo"
var pessoa = Pessoas.pessoas.FirstOrDefault(pessoa => pessoa.CPF == "foo");
if (pessoa is not null) {
    Pessoas.pessoas.Remove(pessoa);
}
```

Você também pode adicionar um método `Remover` na sua classe:

```
public void Remover() {
    Pessoas.pessoas.Remove(this);
}
```

E remover a pessoa usando este método no próprio objeto:

```
p1.Remover();
```

Answer (score 0):

Então, seu código está ótimo. Porém eu tive que fazer de outra forma, pois não sabia qual exatamente seria as informações que o usuário passaria. Eu fiz da seguinte maneira:

Criei um `LinkButton` dentro da minha `GridView` assim:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridResultado" runat="server" CssClass="tblDados">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Excluir" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Excluir" OnClick="Excluir_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Dentro do `onClick` do botão, inseri o seguinte código:

```
protected void Excluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var id = ((System.Web.UI.Control)sender).ClientID;
        var ID = Int32.Parse(id.Remove(0, 22));
                
        Pessoas.pessoas.RemoveAt(ID);
        gridResultado.DataBind();
    }
```

Ele pega o ClientId do botão que consequentemente termina com `_(número da linha)`. Depois eu o transformo em int e eu dou um `Trim` para cortar as letras que eu não quero e pegar somente o número do final. Depois disso seleciono pessoas da classe Pessoas e dou um `RemoveAt` (não pode ser só `Remove`) no ID (segunda variável que eu criei). Por último, dou um `DataBind()` na minha `GridView` para ela atualizar, assim, removendo aquela pessoa (com todas as informações dela) da minha Lista Pessoas que só está salva na MEMÓRIA (não uso banco de dados).

Comment: Dei a resposta com base no código que você disponibilizou na sua pergunta inicial

Comment: Sim, meu amigo, por isso não falei mais nada. Só não era exatamente o que eu precisava. Mas creio que eu me expressei mal. Obrigado pela ajuda de qualquer forma.